# Question based on infimum concept

Tags: real-analysis

Somebody told me that infimum of smaller set is always bigger than infimum of bigger set .I couldnot understand it how ? How can it be justified ?

Comment: please elaborate your question more. Is it infimum OVER a set(of a function)? or just infimum of a set?

Comment: By "smaller set," I have to assume you mean a proper subset... Otherwise, you could just look at (for example) the sets $\{1\}$ and $\{2,3\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not "always bigger" -- "never smaller." To see why, take the infimum $m$ of the bigger set $S$. For all $s\in S$, $m \leq s$ by definition. But for any subset $T\subseteq S$, you have that for any $t\in T$, $t\in S$: so $m \leq t$ as well. That is, $m$ is a lower bound on $T$ -- in particular, it is not greater than the infimum of $T$, which is the *greatest* lower bound for $T$ possible.

Comment: Shouldn't it be subset T of S in second line

Comment: If i take set {1,2,3,4,5,6} and subset to be {3,4,5} then infimum of subset if bigger than infimum of set itself

Comment: Yes, but it's not *always* bigger. It just cannot be smaller (i.e., you have in general $\leq$, not $<$). Take $\{0,1,2\}$ and $\{0,1\}$, for instance -- the infimum is the same.